# Can I use a pre-Unibody optical bay adapter in a Unibody MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive, hard-drive, drive-bay

I have a 3rd-party drive adapter which allows me to put a 2nd hard drive in the optical drive bay of a [2008 MacBook Pro](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/stats/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-15-early-2008-penryn-specs.html). I'm looking at getting a [2010 Unibody MacBook Pro](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/stats/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.4-aluminum-15-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html); is this adapter likely to be compatible, or will I have to buy a new one?

Comment: Well which 3rd-party drive adapter are you using?

Comment: Alas, I don't actually remember. :( The iFixit model has separate models for Unibody and pre-Unibody, while the MCE Optibay does not. However, I'm also not seeing any reason why iFixit would have separate models, as far as I can tell it's the same protocols and form factor.

Comment: w/o you bay model, it is hard to answer... got the MCE one in a 2009 MBP (unibody) that fits perfectly. You could just try! read that some people was even doing it without an adapter, just using tricks to fix hdd... that could be a temporary solution until you get a new one if your doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the new MacBook, and it turns that the optical drive uses a different type of connector, so alas, the old bay adapter is not compatible.

Comment: the old one is likely atapi, the new one is likely sata...

Answer (score 0):

According to this [iFixit guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Late-2008-and-Early-2009-Optical-Drive-Replacement/826/1) (I hope i have the guide for your model) the following product is necessary: [9.5 mm SATA Optical Bay SATA Hard Drive Enclosure](http://www.ifixit.com/Apple-Parts/9-5-mm-SATA-Optical-Bay-SATA-Hard-Drive-Enclosure/IF107-080?utm_source=ifixit_guide&utm_medium=guide_intro&utm_content=required_items&utm_term=macbook_pro_15%22_unibody_late_2008_and_early_2009)

And the product information says:

```
This product works in:
All Unibody MacBooks and Unibody MacBook Pros
```

So you should be good to go ;)

Comment: He mentions *pre-unibody*, i.e.  his adapter is *not designed for Unibody enclosures*. Your answer doesn't make any sense at all to me...